# Using QPointF with Big Doubles

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I am looking some advice for a Qt program I am working on, that uses Qwt to draw a line graph.

Basically my problem arises from the graph's x axis, which is in 24:00 time. I have a `QPolygonF` that stores a series of `QPointF`s that hold the values for my plot curve, where every `1.0` in the x axis equates to 1 second. I then use unix timestamps to set each value for the x axis, so basically I have `double xAxis` initialised to `0.0` which is added to the `QPolygonF` like `points.append(xAxis, yAxis)` for the start of curve and for each point thereafter I use `currentTime - prevTime` to find the difference between both timestamps and then increase `xAxis` by said difference using `+=`. If that makes sense.

Anyway, currently everything is displayed in whole seconds and it works perfectly fine. However, I need it to be precise to the millisecond. What I need some guidance on is working with large high precision doubles.

Working with unix timestamps in seconds is easy as that can be done with a simple `int`, but when you increase the number of digits to include milliseconds `double`s are switched to scientific notation.

My question is: how do I store potentially large numbers, like 22429.388 or larger, if they revert to scientific notation?

Thanks and sorry if this is a very basic question.

Answer (score 0):

You say you graph axis is `24:00` long. This will be `24*3600` seconds, so `24*3600*1000` milliseconds: `86,400,000` which is way smaller than `INT_MAX` (`=2,147,483,647`).

So there should be no problem storing your `x` values as an `int`. You just need to make first axis value be `0` then last axis value will be `86,400,000`.

If your times do not start at 0, you just need to define the smallest time displayed as a "reference date" and store values based on this "reference date" (to guarantee they will all be between `00:00:00.0000` (i.e: `0` as an `int`) and `24:00:00.0000` (i.e: `86,400,000` as an `int`)).

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm sorry I meant the graph is displayed in `hh:mm`. It could be longer than 24 hours. I use `int`s currently, which is perfectly fine for precision up to `hh:mm:ss`. I'll try to be clearer this time: the problem I encounter is using large numbers with `doubles`, which I need for the `QPointF` that holds the coordinates for my plot curve. As doubles only hold up to 6 digits before switching to scientific notation, the max `double` I can have is 999.999 which is around 16 mins. If the difference between `currentTime - prevTime` is more than 17 mins I cannot calculate it.

Comment: double has a much better precision than what you say. If you get only three digits, it's just that you don't print it right. Where have you seen that 999.999 would be the biggest value you could get?